# Is possible create a custom warning with comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, warnings, customization, markup

On Xcode is possible create custom comments warnings to markup the code with important informations. Exist or is possible create the same functionality in VSCode ?

Comment: You mean you want to somehow highlight pieces of code?

Answer (score 1):

Extension: **[TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight)**. You can customize colors, keywords and other stuff.

[image]